# Qt with MSVS2010 - error compilation

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I have a problem with a Qt project in MSVS2010. I compiled the Qt library using the Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010) and installed, in addition to Qt, the Visual Studio Add-In. So when I create a Qt project like a Qt console application all is ok. I can use all libraries of Qt (to test I used QString and application compile and run).

When I want to create a Qt application I can do it, but when I want to try and compile it, it does not work and writes:

> error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1

Do you know what it is? And what can I do so that application compiles and runs?

> 1>------ Build started: Project: mma, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>
> 1>  Moc'ing mma.h...
>
> 1>  Uic'ing mma.ui...
>
> 1>  File 'C:\Users\Micha?\workspace\mma\mma\mma.ui' is not valid
>
> 1>  Rcc'ing mma.qrc...
>
> 1>  C:\Qt\4.7.4\bin\rcc.exe: File does not exist 'C:\Users\Micha?\workspace\mma\mma\mma.qrc'
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Is a .ui file generated at the correct location? Is there a .qrc file at the correct location? Did you check whether or not the question mark in your path is causing problems?

Comment: Did you check path of the ui and  qrc file? There is a strange '?' in it.

Comment: Thanks. I did not see it. This mark '?' is because my folder where i have my project is Michał but 'ł' change to ?(but i donot know why). Problem was solved when i change path of forlder project without Polish mark. Now all complite and run.

Thank you very much for help me.